# How to make a comparison between the current date and two arbitrary dates?

Tags: xslt, date-comparison

I have a requirement to compare the current date with start and end dates in XSLT 1.0. Can anyone help on this?

Here is an example: I need to determine whether 2017-02-15 is between 2017-02-14 and 2017-02-16.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: @bahrep (and the rest of you): Actually, this is a legitimate question. Sure, it could use an example of the input and the expected output - but it *is* pointing at a specific difficulty. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the problem with this question IMO is that it does not tell about this specific difficulty and how OP tried to complete his task before asking on StackOverflow. Some code example would also be great. Anyway, I'm voting to reopen this question, too. However, there is a great chance that it will be closed again as a duplicate. I see similar questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare dates as such, but you can compare them as numbers after removing the `-`separator, for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="datenum" select="translate(YourDate, '-', '')" />
<xsl:if test="20170214 &lt;= $datenum and $datenum &lt;= 20170216">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:if>
```